# W: Target package multiple times Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I got these after i run

```
sudo apt update
```

Here's the complete list:

```
rice@EverRed:~$ sudo apt update
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]   
Get:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [10.2 kB]           
Get:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic/partner i386 Packages [2,300 B]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]   
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages [147 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic/partner amd64 Packages [2,304 B]
Get:8 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic/partner Translation-en [1,272 B]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB] 
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages [1,019 kB]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages [186 kB]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main Translation-en [72.1 kB]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [204 B]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [29 B]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [29 B]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages [89.0 kB]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages [89.0 kB]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe Translation-en [48.5 kB]
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [9,384 B]
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [9,088 B]
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [16.3 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse i386 Packages [1,608 B]
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [1,440 B]
Get:24 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse Translation-en [996 B]
Get:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages [1,007 kB]
Get:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main Translation-en [516 kB]
Get:27 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [477 kB]
Get:28 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [118 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [245 kB]
Get:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted amd64 Packages [9,184 B]
Get:31 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9,156 B]
Get:32 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted Translation-en [3,584 B]
Get:33 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages [8,570 kB]
Get:34 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages [8,531 kB]
Get:35 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe Translation-en [4,941 kB]
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,287 kB]
Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [2,151 kB]
Get:38 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [8,420 kB]
Get:39 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse amd64 Packages [151 kB]
Get:40 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse i386 Packages [144 kB]
Get:41 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse Translation-en [108 kB]
Get:42 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [49.7 kB]
Get:43 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse DEP-11 48x48 Icons [8,931 B]
Get:44 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [225 kB]
Get:45 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [407 kB]
Get:46 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [366 kB]
Get:47 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main Translation-en [152 kB]
Get:48 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [185 kB]
Get:49 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [44.5 kB]
Get:50 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [86.2 kB]
Get:51 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [7,028 B]
Get:52 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted i386 Packages [6,976 B]
Get:53 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted Translation-en [3,076 B]
Get:54 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [565 kB]
Get:55 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages [560 kB]
Get:56 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe Translation-en [148 kB]
Get:57 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [191 kB]
Get:58 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [174 kB]
Get:59 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [297 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [5,708 B]
Get:61 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [5,864 B]
Get:62 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse Translation-en [3,176 B]
Get:63 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,468 B]
Get:64 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse DEP-11 48x48 Icons [29 B]
Get:65 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [2,638 B]
Get:66 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 Packages [2,852 B]
Get:67 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe i386 Packages [2,848 B]
Get:68 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe Translation-en [1,200 B]
Get:69 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,100 B]
Get:70 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [29 B]
Get:71 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [1,789 B]
Fetched 44.4 MB in 21s (2,136 kB/s)                                            
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:44 and /etc/apt/sources.list:87
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:44 and /etc/apt/sources.list:87
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:44 and /etc/apt/sources.list:87
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:44 and /etc/apt/sources.list:87
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:44 and /etc/apt/sources.list:87
W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:44 and /etc/apt/sources.list:87
W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:44 and /etc/apt/sources.list:87
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (partner/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:44 and /etc/apt/sources.list:87
W: Target DEP-11-icons (partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:44 and /etc/apt/sources.list:87
W: Target CNF (partner/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:44 and /etc/apt/sources.list:87
W: Target CNF (partner/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:44 and /etc/apt/sources.list:87
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:44 and /etc/apt/sources.list:87
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:44 and /etc/apt/sources.list:87
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:44 and /etc/apt/sources.list:87
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:44 and /etc/apt/sources.list:87
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:44 and /etc/apt/sources.list:87
W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:44 and /etc/apt/sources.list:87
W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:44 and /etc/apt/sources.list:87
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (partner/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:44 and /etc/apt/sources.list:87
W: Target DEP-11-icons (partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:44 and /etc/apt/sources.list:87
W: Target CNF (partner/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:44 and /etc/apt/sources.list:87
W: Target CNF (partner/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:44 and /etc/apt/sources.list:87
```

I did some research and people said just delete files in source.list.d but there's nothing in there and also here is my source.list:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725)]/ bionic main restricted
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

Comment: I actually just deleted a whole block that contains line 87 and it's fine now. I should have done that before I posted the question. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `deb`defined in sources.list

**1st there is in :**

```
...
...    
## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
...
...
```

**2nd there is in :**

```
...
...
## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
...
...
```

**Please** add `#` in

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
```

and update/upgrade your apt.

Hope this helps.